# How to make a new parition out of unallocated partition using gparted?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, gparted

I wanted to make a new partition to install ubuntu on it. I was successfully able to resize another partition to get some unallocated space but now I'm unable to make a new partition from the unallocated space.

When I right click on the unallocated space and click on "New", I get this screen.

[image]

But I don't get what to write in "Partition name" and "Label". Can I just give it any name or is it something else?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you are trying to prepare the drive for installing Ubuntu, unallocated space is actually what you need. I would not recommend creating a partition ahead of time. When you begin the installation you should choose the unallocated space as the destination for the installation.

Comment: If for a / (root) partition, I like to use the version like focal or groovy. Since I installed focal a second time using Kubuntu, I named it focal_k. I use data partitions and label as data since various folders in it. You can label whatever makes sense to you, but label also should be unique as they can be used to identify partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave this fields empty if you want, so no partition name or label will be set.

If you want to set a partition name and/or label, they should be unique in your system since they can be used to identify a partition for example in `/etc/fstab`.

If you set both, you should use the same name for the partition name and the label to avoid confusion.

- The partition name is only available for GPT and is stored in the partition table
- The label is a file-system property and is stored in the superblock of the file-system.

In a default installation, the UUID of the file-system is used to identify a partition. A UUID is a long string, a mix of letters and numbers, it does not tell you anything about the content of a partition. That's what labels and partition names are for, but you need to define them yourself. It makes sense to chose a name or label which describes the content of your partition, so you can easily identify your partitions in Gparted or other command output like `lsblk -f`.